open Activity with the display off on wear os
I'm trying to implement the same behavior as the alarm clock app on wear OS.
I tried using NotificationCompat with setFullScreenIntent and wakelock but I can't open an activity to receive feedback.
The code used:
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

    val powerManager = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    val wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
        PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK or
                PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK or
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
        "app::feedback"
    )

    wakeLock.acquire(10000)


    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        showNotification(context)
    }, 1000) // secondi = 1 secondo di ritardo


}

private fun showNotification(context: Context) {
    val intent = Intent(context, FullScreenActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    }

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        0,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )

    val vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 500, 250, 500)  // Vibra per 500ms, pausa di 250ms, vibra per 500ms


    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_vector_test)
        .setContentTitle("Timer Scaduto")
        .setContentText("Il tuo timer è scaduto!")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
        .setVibrate(vibrationPattern)
        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .build()

    val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(generateRandomNotificationId(), notification)
}
private fun generateRandomNotificationId(): Int {
    return (System.currentTimeMillis() % Int.MAX_VALUE).toInt()
}

}
while I get this behavior, i.e. with the screen off  activates and shows me the notification in full screen but it is not customizable.

any suggestions?

why don't you just start an activity? your code is a notification only.

I should start the activity with the screen off but on wearos it doesn't seem to work

you will never get an answer if you do not show how you tried to start the activity. starting an activity from an alarm is definitely working. Your code is a notification, not an activity.

I updated the code, basically I have an alarmreceiver that launches the notification at a certain time, the initial idea was to start a full screen intent but it doesn't work, how can I update and start an activity instead?

you don't need a wakelock. and you don't need a notification. delete everything except this line:
val intent = Intent(context, FullScreenActivity::class.java).apply {
flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
}
and then simply call
context.startActivity(intent)
that's it.

I can't start an intent directly, it doesn't work, the screen remains off and no intent is started, perhaps I explained the problem badly!

sorry, i looked in my code because i'm working on this app for over 3 years now and i just didn't remember.
you need to ask for the permission ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION.\n
code if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {             val overlayPermissionIntent = Intent(                 Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse(                     "package:$packageName"                 )             )             startForResult.launch(overlayPermissionIntent)         }

it can work as a solution, thanks
